# How to check whether a directory exists before inserting a file

Tags: asp.net

I have a path like `C:\application\photo\gallery\sketches`.

Now I need to check whether this entire path exits or not before inserting a file into this location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Directory.Exists Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) is what you're looking for:

```
using System.IO;

//...

if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
{
    // your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx).